# Android Sliding Drawer

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

I want to make 2 Sliding Drawers with Relative Layout (so the first sliding drawer is in front of the second sliding drawer). The first sliding drawer's content has a button to Open Second Sliding Drawer.

When i open the first sliding drawer only cover 1/3 of the screen. The second sliding drawer cover all of the screen.

Now i want to:

When i click the button on the content of first sliding drawer, it opens the second sliding drawer, like i said before, AND THEN i want the handler of the first sliding drawer GONE. It becomes VISIBLE again after the second sliding drawer is closed. So basically, i can't close the first sliding drawer, if the second sliding drawer is still opened.

I already tried to setVisibility(View.GONE) and setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) but it doesn't work.

Sorry i can't post picture in this forum so it maybe a bit confusing. Thanks for answering ;)

Comment: Have a look around in highly rated applications within the Play Store and reconsider if you are *really sure* that you want to use a SlidingDrawer.

Comment: @Keyboardsurfer why? can't i use sliding drawer for this?

Comment: You can use it. But using the SlidingDrawer can be painful. This is why I reccommend using something different than the SlidingDrawer.

Comment: @Keyboardsurfer Oh thanks for your advice. But i don't know what to use beside the sliding drawer because i want (my boss actually) to make it have an animation to slide up and down so i thought of using sliding drawer.

Comment: You could use Fragments with custom animations.

Comment: Can it be developed in android 2.2? I see that it needs API 11 and android 2.2's API is 8

Comment: Yes, but you'll need to use the [CompatibilityLibrary](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html). edit: That's enough off topic knowledge for now.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just closing the first drawer when you touch the button for the second one?

```
slidingDrawer1.close();
```

Comment: emm..actually i don't want the first drawer to be closed when the second drawer is opened.

Comment: Then your question could use some clarification, because that's what I got from it.  :)  And now I'm really confused as to what you're trying to do.

Comment: I know it's confusing without picture. I tried to put picture but i'm not allowed to do that because my reputation is below 10. Sorry, but thanks for the answer. ;)

Comment: According to the question asked, this is exactly what you're looking for @kyuu. "i can't close the first sliding drawer, if the second sliding drawer is still opened"